# PHP - Turn a timestamp (2012-07-12 20:26:00) Into two seperate variables that refelct the month and day values?

Tags: php, regex, string, strip

I would like to separately strip the day and month values out of this  timestamp "2012-07-12 17:50:00".

So essentially I could have two variables like:

```
$month = 7
$day = 12
```

As I am not very proficient with php, specifically regex coding, I thought I would post this question to ask for advice as to how I would go about accomplishing something like this.

Any assistance, insight or input in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

AS A NOTE: Futhermore, I would like to turn the two variables into an output like "12th July". This can be coded quite easily so I have not made this a part of the question but if there is a simple function that deals with this information would be much appreciated too!

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation for the DateTime class

Comment: @GordonM Thanks, I will Google that now and see if its relevant.

Comment: Is that a mysql date/time value? If is, you'd be far better off simply doing `select day(yourfield) as day, month(yourfield) as month` instead. Beyond that, there'd be `select date_format(yourfield, '%D %M')` to select your formatted version directly

Comment: @MarcB It is a mysql timestamp value. I am a bit confused about your response though. Say for instance my field was "timestamp" I should run `select day(timestamp) as day, month(timestamp) as month` and it would reflect the values i need as results?

Comment: @BlackberryFan: yes, exactly. mysql has a huge library of date/time functions you can use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  it's better to do the date conversions there, because if you do it in php, you're forcing the system to do multiple native->string->native->string->etc... conversion cycles. doing it in mysql directly does a SINGLE conversion.

Comment: @MarcB Given my desired output, do you not think it would be better in this instance to keep the timestamp intact? The only way I can really think of is using a bit of actual php code like if...else if...

Comment: you can always pull out the timestamp as well, `select yourfield, date_format(yourfield, ...), etc...`. you can use a field and derivatives of that field as many times as you want in the select's field list.

Comment: @MarcB You have blown my mind! You always help me with my petty problems, thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
list($month,$day) = explode(':',date('n:j',strtotime('2012-07-12 17:50:00')),2);
echo 'Month: '.$month.'<br />'."\n";//Month: 7
echo 'Day: '.$day.'<br />'."\n";//Day: 12
?>
```

And...

```
<?php
echo date('jS F',strtotime('2012-07-12 17:50:00'));//Outputs: 12th July
?>
```

Comment: I do believe that you have answered my question perfectly. Thank you so much! Please see my comment to Talisin in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, DateTime would be a good choice.

First, if your php config dosen't already set it up for you, set your default timezone by:

```
date_default_timezone_set('XXXX');
```

XXXX stand for a value out of the [List of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

initialize your date by:

```
$DateTime = new DateTime();
```

depending on where you get the timestamp, lets assume you will create it out of PHP:

```
$timestamp = $DateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Now format the output

```
echo $month = $DateTime->format( 'm' );
echo $day = $DateTime->format( 'd' );
```

or to get you desired output:

```
echo $output = $DateTime->format( 'dS F' );
```

Comment: This is a good answer, it deserves more than one star :) But I have a question, in the last like you format as `dS`, whereas it is `jS` in the answer given below by polishHurricane. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: @BlackberryFan,
`d = 01 to 31 (leading zeros)
j = 1 to 31 (non-leading zeros)`

Comment: you can find all available formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the timestamp is a string, something like this should work if you're looking for a regex solution...

```
<?php
$string = '2012-07-12 17:50:00';
preg_match_all('/\d{4}-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', $string, $matches);
$month =$matches[1][0];
$day = $matches[2][0];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly how I was thinking. But Now I am not quite sure if it will be the best possible solution. I need time to think :)